# Rails 3 and Sunspot, rdoc or good tuto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, sunspot, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to **sunspot** and **rails 3**, so I followed this little tuto:
http://github.com/exempla/sunspot

But there is not a lot of details, and the official github of outoftime/sunspot do not speak much about the **rails 3** version.

ex: How can I do a `rake sunspot:reindex`

So if anyone know where I can find some good rdoc for the **rails 3** version of **sunspot** it will be great

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the rails3 version code is ready, but if you grab the sunspot_rails folder on github.com/isaac/sunspot, copy that to your `/lib directory`, create a `/config/sunspot.yml` and a `/config/initializers/sunspot.rb` with:

```
require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'sunspot', 'rails', 'adapters', 'active_record')
```

Also add `require 'sunspot/rails/tasks'` to Rakefile

You should be ok.

Comment: Hi max,

My team and I, fanally take the decision to wait for the plugin thinking_sphinx 2.0, whitch should work with rails 3

http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/be01336608364b93/6e1563b44f242187?lnk=gst&q=rails+3#6e1563b44f242187